# Mysql join practices use LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN only?

Tags: mysql, left-join, inner-join, right-join

As I am reading about joins I realize that only two of those are in work as others are just the same. Am I correct?

`INNER JOIN` = `JOIN`
`LEFT JOIN` = `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Are there any joins that you actually use?

Comment: [JOINs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html:

```
join_table:
    table_reference [INNER | CROSS] JOIN table_factor [join_condition]
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor
  | table_reference STRAIGHT_JOIN table_factor ON conditional_expr
  | table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_condition
  | table_reference NATURAL [{LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER]] JOIN table_factor
```

Text within the braces is optional.  The `INNER` and `CROSS` keywords are optional for a normal `JOIN` (the documentation mentions this).  The `OUTER` keyword is optional for outer (`LEFT`|`RIGHT`) joins.

This could be a bit clearer in that `NATURAL LEFT JOIN` is not the same as `NATURAL JOIN`, but the `INNER`, `CROSS`, and `OUTER` keywords are optional when used in the correct spot.

Note that this is MySQL specific.  It is *not* the case in standard SQL.